# How to check the selected Items

Tags: vb6

Using VB6

In the Form, i am having 2 list box name as lstDivison, lstDepartment

Code

```
    For I = 0 To lstDivision.ListCount - 1
    If lstDivision.Selected(I) = True Then
        Filter = ""
        Filter = lstDivision.List(I)
        Divison
    Else
        ViewAll
    End If
    Next


    For I = 0 To lstDepartment.ListCount - 1
    If lstDepartment.Selected(I) = True Then
        Filter = ""
        Filter = lstDepartment.List(I)
        Department
    Else
        ViewAll
    End If
    Next
```

Above code is working, but i want to know which listbox value is selected.

Conditon

```
If lstDivison list item is selected then it should not check the lstDepartment, if lstDepartment list item is selected then it should not check the lstDivison...
```

Code like this...

```
If lstDivison.selected = true then

some code

ElseIf lstDeartment.Selected = true then

some code

Else

Some code

End If
```

How to do this.

Need VB6 Code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to ensure that only one of the listbox controls has a selected value at each time, by letting the listboxes clear the selection from the other listbox when selected.  This makes it somewhat clearer to the user what values to expect from the filter, since there will only be selected values in one listbox at a time.

To do this, you can add this code:

```
private sub lstDepartment_Click()
  For I = 0 to lstDivision.ListCount - 1
     lstDivision.Selected(I) = False  
  Next
End Sub

private sub lstDivision_Click()
  For I = 0 to lstDepartment.ListCount - 1
     lstDepartment.Selected(I) = False  
  Next
End Sub
```

After this, your current code will work.